# calculate the percentage of not null recs in a file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

How do i figure out the percentage of not null records in my file in UNIX?

My file like this: I wanted to know the amount of records & the percentage of not null rec's. Tried whole lot of grep n cut commands but nothing seems to be working out. Can anyone help me here please...

```
"name","country","age","place"
 "sam","US","30","CA"
  "","","",""
 "joe","UK","34","BRIS"
  ,,,,
 "jake","US","66","Ohio"
```

Comment: What result do you expect for the given sample and why?

Comment: actually the file above is to show you the kind of file i'm stuck with,the real file is having more than 100k rec. here i'm trying to figure out the percentage of not null records present in reach field. btw is it achievable in unix?

Comment: Is `""` considered "null", or just `,,`?

Comment: "" & ,, are taken as null

Comment: @mac_online, kindly POST a sample of output too for specific set of sample input too in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the fact is , i don't know how the o/p has to be here. I only wanted to know the percentage or the count of not null records from each field.

Comment: If you don;t know what the output is supposed to be, how can we help you write a tool to produce that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.012; # say, keys @arr

use Text::CSV_XS qw{ csv };

my ($count_all, @count_nonempty);

csv(in      => shift,
    out     => \ 'skip',
    headers => 'skip',
    on_in   => sub {
        my (undef, $columns) = @_;
        ++$count_all;
        length $columns->[$_] and $count_nonempty[$_]++
            for 0 .. $#$columns;
    },
);

for my $column (keys @count_nonempty) {
    say "Column ", 1 + $column, ": ",
        100 * $count_nonempty[$column] / $count_all, '%';
}
```

It uses [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) to read the CSV file. It skips the header line, and for each subsequent line, it calls the callback specified in `on_in`, which increments the count of all lines and also the count of empty fields per column if the length of a field is zero.

Comment: how do i execute this in linux? and where should i plug the file name. can u pl advise

Comment: You save it to a file, e.g. `percentage.pl`, then run `perl percentage.pl -- file.csv`.

Comment: not sure why the prompt is blocking me with this error.    Can't locate Text/CSV_XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at percentage.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at percentage.pl line 6.

Comment: You need to install [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS). Your vendor might provide the package for you, search for something like `perl-Text-CSV_XS` or similar in your package manager.

Comment: Or install it with `cpan Text::CSV_XS`, but you'll likely need to install all the system build-essentials too.

Comment: i don't have all the privileges to install that in my  work comp ;-(

Comment: Then your company is not providing you what you need to do your job.

Comment: You can configure Perl to install libraries to your user directory. See [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib) - but it's a bit more complex.

Comment: thanks man. i'm so happy to see alot of helping ppl around me. let me give it one more try and let u know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Along with choroba, I would normally recommend using a CSV parser on CSV data.

But in this case, all we want to look for is that a record contains any character that is not a comma or quote: if a record contains only commas and/or quotes, it is a "null" record.

```
awk '
    /[^",]/ {nonnull++}
    END {printf "%d / %d = %.2f\n", nonnull, NR, nonnull/NR}
' file
```

---

To handle leading/trailing whitespace

```
awk '
    {sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,""); sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/,"")}
    /[^",]/ {nonnull++}
    END {printf "%d / %d = %.2f\n", nonnull, NR, nonnull/NR}
' file
```

If allowing fields containing only whitespace, such as

```
 "  ","",,," "
```

is also a null record, we can simple ignore all whitespace

```
awk '
    /[^",[:blank:]]/ {nonnull++}
    END {printf "%d / %d = %.2f\n", nonnull, NR, nonnull/NR}
' file
```

Comment: i got a result like this $ awk ' /[^",]/ {nonnull++} END {printf "%d / %d = %.2f\n", nonnull, NR, nonnull/NR}' elopzitch.txt
13384 / 13384 = 1.00   . does this mean there's only 1% of null recs?

Comment: You must have whitespace in your file. I'll update my answer

Comment: but the o/p that i get is still 13384 / 13384 = 1.00, does it mean that the file has 1% null recs? having a hard time to decipher the results here

Comment: That means the file is 100% not null records.

Comment: gotcha! is it possible to get col wise percentage of not null recs

Comment: Yes it it possible. Don't add requirements in comments: either update your question or ask a new question.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i have added it in the ticket desc to find out the percentage of not null rec's too.